# Can the Async CTP be used with a portable library

Tags: c#, async-ctp, portable-class-library

I was looking to see if the Async CTP with a portable class library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The Async CTP has different dlls for Desktop, Phone, Silverlight 4, and Silverlight 5.

Hopefully in the near future, all these platforms will support Task (and async) natively, and then portable class libraries would be able to use async.

**Update:** [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) can be installed for portable libraries targeting .NET 4.0/4.5, Windows Store apps, Silverlight 4/5, and Windows Phone 7.5/8.0

Comment: This is what I found with my testing. For the meantime I think it is easier to just maintain two different core libraries as there are a few other libs that have the same requirements.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2012 RTM async/await syntax **can be used** in Portable Class Libraries, at least when targeting .NET 4.5 and WinRT.
**Edit**: It's now possible to use async/await even in Portable Class Libraries targeting WP7.5/WP8 + Silverlight 4/5 + .NET 4.0/4.5 + WinRT using [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx) library.

Answer (score 2):

As a heads up, we've started planning a release of Async that will support down-level (.NET 4.0, SL5, Phone 7.5) portable:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2691068-support-async-in-portable-class-libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can use beta version of [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/1.0.12-beta) - I already use it in my projects and it behaves stable to be used in real projects.