# How to create a Thread in a portable class library?

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

F# code targeted for xbox360 using xna does not compile after I convert the project to a portable class library.

```
let thread = Thread(fun () ->
    setAffinity()
```

Thread gets red squiggles and the error message says

> Error 1   This type has no accessible object constructors

Sure enough, if I look at mscorlib in the object explorer, the type has no constructor.
Yet according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx3ezzs2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the constructor exists on xbox and in the PCL.

Edit: I tried with a C# PCL, and I got the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating threads is not portable.  Your link is wrong, it doesn't talk about PCL.

This is the cost of using the Portable Class Library, it is what's left over after subtracting everything that isn't supported by at least one of the possible targets.  Which doesn't leave much, the PCL is quite small.  The biggest hang-up is a target that isn't actually mentioned as supported, yet, WinRT (aka Metro).  It has a severely restricted api.

Consider ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() instead.  I assume that Task is going to be supported some day in the PCL.  It is a work in progress right now.

Comment: The link does say "Supported in: Portable Class Library" towards the end. Thanks for the suggestion about `QueueUserWorkItem()`, but that's not an option my case, as I want to control which core the thread runs on, and I doubt the thread pool will provide the kind of low latency games require.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a documentation bug.  Can't annotate the MSDN article, David Kean keeps an eye on the tag at SO so hopefully sees it.

Comment: What is so "not portable" in creating new Thread ? 
For example if i share code between .net and Windows Phone ?

Comment: Microsoft claims `Thread` exists in Windows Phone Silverlight 7.0 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx - so why is `Thread` inaccessible in a PCL that targets **only** WPS 8.0 and .NET 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

Not to be glib but this sounds like a bug and that's how I would proceed. Send it to fsbugs at Microsoft dot com

Comment: `fsbugs` don't deal with .NET bugs, only F# bugs (as the name implies).

Comment: It sounded like a problem with F# creating the PCL properly which is why I made the suggestion.

Comment: I have now tried with a C# project and got the same error. I have therefore removed the F# tag from my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a BETA release which supports async in .NET 4.0, SL5, Phone 7.5. See David Kean's post on this thread:

[Can the Async CTP be used with a portable library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152634/can-the-async-ctp-be-used-with-a-portable-library)

and this post on the BCL blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx